# Restoring ravendb database having database folder backed up

Tags: .net, ravendb

I copied ravendb database folder from following hard drive location

```
Db backup\Database\Databases\cities
```

where cities is name of the database.
inside this folder there is following files and folders

- IndexDefinitions/
- Indexes/
- logs/
- system/
- temp/
- Data

Data file should contains db data I need, it's pretty big in size.

Since in the meantime I install new windows I reinstall same version of ravendb server (RavenDB-Build-2935) and try to simply trough ravendb server interface to create cities db and copy whole folder into

```
C:\RavenDB-Build-2935\Server\Database\Databases
```

Following error is occured when raven server is executed:

> Couldn't open database named: cities One or more errors occured.

p.s. I'm aware that I'm not exported db as normal but I'm trying to find a way to import this data somehow back into db since I do have backup of Data file (which should have data needed to restore db, I hope :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Raven Smuggler command line tool](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/java/server/administration/exporting-and-importing-data)? It is designed for restoring backups.

What you're trying to do, just xcopy a database from another machine, isn't likely to work. If you read the Raven Smuggler documentation, there's a big warning at the top of the page:

> "Copying Data folder between servers or even within a single server
>   instance is not supported and can result in various server errors."

Just use Smuggler instead.